# Runing commands installing nodejs in a new docker container works, but fails in a Dockerfile?

Tags: docker, dockerfile

So my Dockerfile looks like that:

```
# start from base
FROM ubuntu:18.04

# install system-wide deps for node
RUN apt-get -yqq update
RUN apt-get install -yq wget
RUN wget -qO- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nvm-sh/nvm/v0.34.0/install.sh | bash
ENV NVM_DIR="$HOME/.nvm"
RUN [ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh"
RUN [ -s "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion" 
RUN nvm install v10.15.1
RUN nvm use v10.15.1
...
```

And when I try to build and image it fails on:

```
Step 6/13 : RUN [ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh"
 ---> Running in e46106d9dfd8
The command '/bin/sh -c [ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && \. 
"$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh"' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

What I don't understand is why when I run ubuntu:18.04 image and execute all the commands in the terminal everything succeeds? How can I fixt that, I am new to docker btw.

Comment: Don’t use a version manager like `nvm` or `rvm` or similar tools like Python virtual environments in Docker.  (They will “deactivate” on every new `RUN` instruction and container invocation.)  Just install the version of Node (or whatever) as the “system” version in `/usr` or `/usr/local` inside the image.

Comment: @David Maze Can you explain why nvm doesn't work here from what I read online it is just a tool to install node js. And how do you install it as a system version?

Comment: Where you run `. nvm.sh` it’s tricky in Docker to make that “stick”.  Since a Docker image generally contains one application and its supporting runtime, you also don’t need to have multiple versions of Node installed at once, or to switch back and forth.  I’d just follow the installation instructions on nodejs.org, or `apt-get install` whatever Ubuntu has packaged, rather than install a tool to install a tool for you.